# How to hide the status bar showing link URLs in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, kiosk

I am studying about using Firefox as a kiosk, I found the useful add-on called R-kiosk， it works like charmed， but I found a question that I don't have a solution for.

When I move the cursor to a link or image,it will show bar about this link URL or image URL in the lower left corner of Firefox.

[image]

How do I hide this?

Comment: Check this http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/target_url_hiding.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [style the user interface of Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes) with a css file, `userChrome.css` in the `<profile_root>/chrome` folder.

The easiest way to get the path to the profile folder is to navigate to the url `about:profiles`.

You will likely need to create the userChrome.css file, as it doesn't exist by default. Add the following to the CSS:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

statuspanel {display:none!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version 61

```
statuspanel {display:none!important;}
```

has changed to:

```
#statuspanel {display:none!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#statuspanel {display:none!important;}
```

Finally ! I came across a great deal of useless CSS suggestions.
This one is simple and it works ! Thanks to jdphenix and Simone. (Firefox Quantum 62)

Comment: Perhaps you can explain your answer better.